# How to detect combination of key presses on keyboard in linux with python pynput and opencv?

Tags: python, linux, opencv, keypress, pynput

I am working on a project which is about creating an autonomous driver in Linux platform. I need to catch the keys pressed on the keyboard at certain time especially when they are pressed simultaneously. I wrote this code which works really good in windows but not similarly good in linux:

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy as np
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def up():
    print("Go up")


def down():
    print("Go down")


def left():
    print("Go left")


def right():
    print("Go right")


def up_left():
    print("Go up_left")


def up_right():
    print("Go up_right")


def down_left():
    print("Go down_left")


def down_right():
    print("Go down_right")


def do_nothing():
    print("Do Nothing")


# Create a mapping of keys to function (use frozenset as sets are not hashable - so they can't be used as keys)



# The keys combinatons to check

combination_to_function = {
    frozenset([Key.up]): up,
    frozenset([Key.down, ]): down,
    frozenset([Key.left, ]): left,
    frozenset([Key.right, ]): right,
    frozenset([Key.up, Key.left]): up_left,
    frozenset([Key.up, Key.right]): up_right,
    frozenset([Key.down, Key.left]): down_left,
    frozenset([Key.down, Key.right]): down_right,
}

# Currently pressed keys
current_keys = set()

def on_press(key):
    # When a key is pressed, add it to the set we are keeping track of and check if this set is in the dictionary
    current_keys.add(key)
    if frozenset(current_keys) in combination_to_function:
        # If the current set of keys are in the mapping, execute the function
        combination_to_function[frozenset(current_keys)]()


def on_release(key):
    # When a key is released, remove it from the set of keys we are keeping track of
    if key in current_keys:
        current_keys.remove(key)


def process_img(original_img):
    processed_img = cv2.cvtColor(original_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    processed_img = cv2.Canny(processed_img, threshold1=200, threshold2=300)
    return processed_img


with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {"top": 0, "left": 70, "width": 640, "height": 480}

    while True:
        listener = Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
        listener.start()
        last_time = time.time()
        # key_catcher = MockButton()
        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        screen = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
        new_screen = process_img(original_img=screen)

        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow("Window", new_screen)

        # print("Loop took {} seconds".format(time.time() - last_time))
        # Press "q" to quit

        k = cv2.waitKey(10)

        if k & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

        listener.stop()
```

The `go_up`, `go_down`, ... functions are just symbolic and I want to write other codes for translating the pressed keys to vectors for machine learning process.

For example if I press `w` on keyboard I expect a vector like this:

```
 w   s   a   d   wa  wd  sa  sd  nk
[1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ]
```

and when I press `w` and `a` together I expect this:

```
 w   s   a   d   wa  wd  sa  sd  nk
[0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0 ]
```

anyway the code is not running good enough in linux. The program come across some issues when running for a while. The terminal stops giving outputs after a while the program is running. would anyone please help me to make this code more efficient in linux??

Comment: why do you use `key_check` if you have `cv2.waitKey()` for this ?

Comment: BTW: `keyList = ["\b"] + list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 123456789,.'£$/\\")` but you don't have to convert string to list to use it in `for key on keyList`. It should works  `for key in "\bABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 123456789,.'£$/\\":`

Comment: BTW: you don't have to use `with ... as listener: listener.join()`. You can run `listener.start()` before your loop and `listener.stop()` after your loop.

Comment: Is it possible to detect keys that are pressed simultaneously with `cv2.waitKey()`? For example for pressing `w` I want certain function to run and for both `w` and `A` I want another function to run. So it's important to catch the right keys.

Comment: with `cv2.waitKey()` after pressing `w` you would have to wait few millisecond (few loops) and if you get `A` in next loops then you run second function. If you don't get `A` then you run first function. But you can't check if didn't release `w` meanwhile. With `listener` you may have to do the same - you would have to wait few loops to check if you didn't press `A` but you can easily check if you didn't release `w`.

Comment: if you get process starvation then you could show current code in question and describe problem with starvation. If you run other threads in code then also show it. Simply you could create minimal working code with starvation.

Comment: @furas did the command sir. Make me happy if you had any ideas!! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you try to do with your `key_check()` but I would expect that you can do the same using `cv2.waitKey()`

---

If you want to use `pynput` then you can do

```
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:

     # your loop

     listener.stop()
     listener.join()
```

or

```
listener = pynput.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
listener.start()

# your loop

listener.stop()
listener.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I updated the question. I need to have the pressed keys at the moment loop reaches the `key_check` function. Do you have any idea?

Comment: in `on_press` use `keyList.append(key)` and in `on_release` use `if key in keyList: keyList.remove(key)` and you will have all pressed key all time. You would have to only sort them. Or use dictionary with keys and set `keys["a"] = True` in `on_press`, and `keys["a"] = False` in `on_release`,